# Can't get a specific property of js object

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, ejs

I am working with ejs, mongodb and express. In ejs file, I have set value of an Edit button to the the js object passed into the ejs file so that I can query required data after in express after the Edit button makes a post request to a route.
EJS edit button code:

```js
<% listOfRecords.forEach((singleRecord)=>{ %>
        <div class="card card-body">
            <form method="post">
                    <button formaction="/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="editBtn" value="<%=singleRecord%>">Edit</button>            
            </form>
        </div>  
    <% }); %>
```

However, I am able console log the js object by the following code in express:

```js
app.post('/edit', (req, res)=>{
    console.log(req.body.editBtn);
});
```

The output of the above code is:

```js
{
  _id: 60605148a1fba61fd8f2446f,
  title: 'asdf',
  author: 'sadf',
  class_section: 'asfd',
  dateIssued: 2021-03-01T00:00:00.000Z,
  __v: 0
}
```

But when I try doing this:
`console.log(req.body.editBtn.title);` 
it shows the error,  `undefined`

What am I doing wrong in this?

Comment: `console.log(typeof req.body.editBtn)`

Comment: @MikeM oh, its showing string and not an object

Comment: @MikeM So what can be the work around for accomplishing the same task now?

Comment: Well, you could use a regular expression to get the title if you dared.

Comment: @MikeM actually I want all the properties of that so how can I do that?

Comment: Ideally, by parsing valid JSON, so you may need to refactor your app to get that. Good luck, I am not able to help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real problem was that `req.body.editBtn` was in String format. So to make this work, change in EJS file would be:

```js
<button formaction="/edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" name="editBtn" value="<%=JSON.stringify(singleRecord)%>">Edit</button>
```

This shall convert js object into a string properly and then in express file, the change is:

```js
let editBtn = req.body.editBtn;
let info = JSON.parse(editBtn);
```

Now I can access any property of the object because it was converted to and from string properly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have enough information. The code from my perspective looks fine. It should work.

What you could try doing is getting the attribute by doing `console.log(req.body.editBtn['title']);` instead of `console.log(req.body.editBtn.title);`.

You could also try destructuring the title : `const { title } = req.body.editBtn`.

Although these should theoretically not work !
Maybe something else in your code is wrong ?

Edit:

If `req.body.editBtn` is a string then try `JSON.parse(req.body.editBtn);` then get the attribute you want.

Comment: Actually the problem is that ```req.body.editBtn``` is in string format so the method of ```editBtn.title``` is not working and when i am trying to do: 
```const info = JSON.parse(req.body.editBtn);``` is showing some more weirder error. Do you know any workaround please?

Answer (score 0):

you should get attributes from *JSON.parse* method's output, rather than req.body.editBtn which is still string.

```
app.post('/edit', (req, res)=>{
    const data = JSON.parse(req.body.editBtn);
    // console.log(req.body.editBtn);
    console.log(data.title);
    console.log(data.author);
    // ....
});
```